# php code igniter using curl for ios push notifications

Tags: php, ios, codeigniter, curl, apple-push-notifications

I've made web-service to send push notifications to ios using curl,
i have the ck.pem file for development which contain both cert & RSA private key, and referring to it correctly.

but every time i call the web-service i get the same error
Curl failed: unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)

All related solutions not working, except alternatives using "stream_context_create", But I want to do it with curl and idk where's the problem is.

find below my code :

```
function test_push_to_ios() {
    $url = 'https://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195';
    $cert = base_url() . 'backend_includes/ios_cert/ck.pem';

    $gcm_ids = array("xxxxxx");
    $passphrase = "passphrase";
    $message = 'nbad_notification';
    $aps = array('alert' => $message, 'sound' => 'default');
    $fields = array('device_tokens' => $gcm_ids, 'data' => $message, 'aps' => $aps);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $cert);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $passphrase);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $cert);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, $passphrase);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't read your question carefully.

You are trying to send push notifications to Apple via an HTTPS request. That can't work. Apple Push Notifications only work with a specific binary format over TCP protocol.

> As a provider you communicate with Apple Push Notification service over a binary interface. This interface is a high-speed, high-capacity interface for providers; it uses a streaming TCP socket design in conjunction with binary content. The binary interface is asynchronous.

There are many problems with your code :

You seem to mix GCM code with APNS code. 
`$fields = array('device_tokens' => $gcm_ids, 'data' => $message, 'aps' => $aps);` looks similar to what you would do when sending a message to Google Cloud Messaging server. But GCM is completely different than APNS, so why did you think that would work?

You are sending a JSON body, which is what works with GCM, but APNS use a binary format. While the payload within the binary message to APNS contains an encoded JSON String (which looks similar to your `$aps` JSON), you can't package it within another JSON and expect it to work.

And adding `https://` in front of the APNS server can't make it support HTTPS, since it wasn't implemented to support HTTPS (nor HTTP).

I suggest you use `stream_context`, which works.

Comment: no, i got the .pem file with both certificate & key , i tried other example using stream_context and it worked. idk why it's not working with curl , did you try my code ?

Comment: @aemad My mistake. I completely changed my answer.

Comment: thanks for the useful info , although i can't make it work , but knowing why really relieving